# Spine.js AJAX fetching record from server

Tags: coffeescript, spine.js

I have simple app which displays list of recrods, also user whould be able to edit barticular record by id.
Because list is big, i don't fetch it as whole, but partially via `Product.fetch(data: $.param(page: 1))`.

Then when someone try to edit record, i call `Product.find(id)` and if recrord was already prefetched with `fetch` then it works fine, but when record not yet fetched then i got error like: `"Product" model could not find a record for the ID "1152"`

So, the question is why `find` not performing ajax call and how to make it perform it or maybe there is another solution exists ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Spine.find` only looks in the already loaded records. Doing an ajax request isn't the function of `find`. So you have to try-catch your find and when it gives this error, you have to fetch it.

```
id = 1152

try
  product = Product.find id
catch err
  Product.fetch(
    data:
     id: id
    processData: true
  )
  # Try again after Product.refresh
```

To be honest, I think this isn't a nice way to do it, but it is how spine works... I rather have it fetch it automatically, or at least not throwing an error on find.

Comment: We are working to improve Spines find and exists features. no more error throwing and allowing find to accept a callback for a fail condition.

Comment: Yes, I saw this in the github repository. I'm really happy this is going to change. Thanks for all the work you put in Spine.